# Extracting specific data from a string with regex using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm returning some data like this in powershell :

```
1)Open;#1

2)Open;#1;#Close;#2;#pending;#6

3)Closed;#5
```

But I want an output like this :

```
1)1 Open

2)

1 Open

2 Close

6 pending

3)

5 Closed
```

The code:

```
$lookupitem = $lookupList.Items
$CMRSItems = $list.Items | where {$_['ID'] -le 5}
$CMRSItems | ForEach-Object {

$realval =  $_['EventType']
Write-Host "RefNumber: " $_['RefID']
Write-Host $realval

}
```

Any help would be appreciated as my powershell isn't that good.

Comment: Can you show the code that gives this output. It's perhaps easier to modify this code than write more code to change the output.

Answer (score 1):

Without regular expressions, you could do something like the following:

```
Ignore everything up to the first ')' character
Split the string on the ';' character
foreach pair of the split string
    the state is the first part (ignore potentially leading '#')
    the number is the second part (ignore leading '#')
```

Or you could do it using the .NET `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` class with the following regular expression:

```
(?:#?(?<state>[a-zA-Z]+);#(?<number>\d);?)
```

The `Captures` property on the `MatchCollection` returned by the `Matches` method would be a collection in which each item will contain two instances in the `Group` collection; named `state` and `number` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Robert.But not that good with powershell :(
Also the string i want to manipulate is "Open;#1;#Close;#2;#pending;#6".this is also a dynamic string not hardcoded

Comment: The format of the strings, e.g `State1;#Num1;#State2;#Num2` is fixed (if it wasn't you'd have a hard time parsing it without a learning algorithm) and both of the above suggested solutions would work well for dynamic strings. I would probably suggest using the regular expression solution. Read up on using .NET classes from PowerShell and read up on the `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` documentation. If you get stuck after having tried, please make a new question asking about help where you're stuck (and add a link here to the new question as a comment to this answer if you do get stuck).